# Как сделать вложенный цикл foreach в for?

Tags: php

Создаю в папке с помощью цикла for документы с разным наполнением. Это наполнение подтягивают из json.
Все отлично работает, но когда дело доходит до того момента, когда из json нужно перебрать массивом данные, скрипт останавливает работу. Как выполнить foreach внутри for?

```
<?

// строка, которую будем записывать
$file = file_get_contents("https://protectorat.cc/api/movies_updates.json?api_token=fa64680c5213b5f16d789133afce4137");
$json = json_decode($file);


for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++)
{
$text = '
<div class="mainblock" id="'.$i. '" style="margin-top: 30px; ">
<div class="film">
  <div class="title_ru">
  <p>'.$json->updates[$i]->title_ru. '</p>
  </div>
  <div class="title_en">
  <p>'.$json->updates[$i]->title_en. '</p>
  </div>
  <div class="year">
  <p>'.$json->updates[$i]->year. '</p>
  </div>
  <div class="duration">
  <p>'.$json->updates[$i]->duration->human. '</p>
  </div>
  <div class="kinopoisk_id">
  <p>'.$json->updates[$i]->kinopoisk_id. '</p>
  </div>
  <div class="token">
  <p>'.$json->updates[$i]->token. '</p>
  </div>
  <div class="source_type">
  <p>'.$json->updates[$i]->source_type. '</p>
  </div>
  <div class="iframe_url">
  <p>'.$json->updates[$i]->iframe_url. '</p>
  </div>
  <div class="translator">
  <p>'.$json->updates[$i]->translator. '</p>
  </div>
  <div class="added_at">
  <p>'.$json->updates[$i]->added_at. '</p>
  </div>

<div class="material_data_country">'; ?>
  <? foreach ($json->updates[$i]->material_data->countries as $countriess) { ?>
  <?  '<span class="countriess" style="display:inline-block;">'.$countriess.'</span>,';?>
    <? } ';

$fp = fopen("empty$i.html", "w");
fwrite($fp, $text);
fclose($fp);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде ошибки.

Исправьте в этих строках, на этот код:

```
  <? foreach ($json->updates[$i]->material_data->countries as $countriess) {
    '<span class="countriess" style="display:inline-block;">'.$countriess.'</span>,';
  }
```

Проверьте весь ваш код.